# Android Room Select @Relation Annotation With Conditions one-to-many Issue

Tags: android, android-room

I have 2 Entities: User and Messages. Every User can have some Messages.

Class User

```
@Entity(tableName = DBConstants.TABLE_USER)
open class User(
        @field:PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Int = 0,
        var appUserId: Int = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        var phoneNumber: String = "",
        var appPackage: @AppPackage String = IN_APP,
        var userType: @UserType Int = CUSTOMER
) : Serializable ,BaseObservable(){
    @field:Ignore
    var messages: ArrayList<Messages> = ArrayList()

    @Bindable
    fun getNumMessages() : Int {
        return messages.size
    }
}
```

And Class Messages

```
@Entity(tableName = TABLE_USER_MESSAGES,
        foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = User::class,
                parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                childColumns = arrayOf("userId"),
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
data class Messages(@field:PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
                    @field:ColumnInfo(name = "userId")
                    var userId: Int = 0,
                    var appUserId: Int = 0,
                    var appPackage: @AppPackage String = IN_APP,
                    var ticker: String = "",
                    var title: String = "",
                    var text: String = "",
                    var date : String)
```

For Select One User - Many Messages. I Created Class UserMessagesView.kt

```
class UserMessagesView {
    @Embedded
    var user : User = User()
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "userId",entity = Messages::class)
    var msg: List<Messages> = ArrayList()
}
```

I use Select Inner Join with Conditions follow this

```
@Dao
abstract class UserMessagesDao : BaseDao<Messages>() {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN messages ON messages.user_id = user.id WHERE messages.date like '%18-11-2018%'")
    abstract fun getAllMessagesByToday(): List<UserMessagesView>
}
```

In databse, I have 1 user in table users with id = 1 
and 4 record messages in table messages foreign key with id user = 1. Follow 2 image 
[TableUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voKNy.png)
[Table Messages][2]

My Issue is When I call method

> getAllMessagesByToday

I received List is size = 4, But First element 'UserMessagesView ' object 'msg' have size = 4 and Others Element object 'msg' size = 0.
And object User in UserMessagesView in List They are the same all field and difference each ID 
Follow Image [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voKNy.png)

In this case I think Room will return 1 record containing a user object and a msg of 4 elements. But it's not exactly what I thought. And I do not know where I went wrong. 
Please help me. It took me 3 days to find out but it did not work. Maybe Room is new and no one has problems like me. Thanks everyone.
Sorry my bad English.

Comment: Please help me !!!!

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?

Comment: Have any one solution for this ?